# Get all possible combinations recursively in an RDD in pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, rdd

I have made this algorithm, but with higher numbers looks like that doesn't work or its very slow, it will run in a cluster of big data(cloudera), so i think that i have to put the function into pyspark, any tip how improve it please

```
import pandas as pd import itertools as itts

number_list = [10953, 10423, 10053]

def reducer(nums): def ranges(n): print(n) return range(n, -1, -1)

num_list = list(map(ranges, nums)) return list(itts.product(*num_list))

data=pd.DataFrame(reducer(number_list)) print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `crossJoin` with DataFrame:

Here we have a simple example trying to compute the cross-product of three arrays, 
i.e. `[1,0], [2,1,0], [3,2,1,0]`. Their cross-product should have 2*3*4 = 24 elements. 
The code below shows how to achieve this.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('test').getOrCreate()
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([(1,),(0,)], ['v1'])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([(2,), (1,),(0,)], ['v2'])
df3 = spark.createDataFrame([(3,), (2,),(1,),(0,)], ['v3'])
df1.show()
df2.show()
df3.show()

+---+
| v1|
+---+
|  1|
|  0|
+---+

+---+
| v2|
+---+
|  2|
|  1|
|  0|
+---+

+---+
| v3|
+---+
|  3|
|  2|
|  1|
|  0|
+---+


df = df1.crossJoin(df2).crossJoin(df3)
print('----------- Total rows: ', df.count())
df.show(30)

----------- Total rows:  24
+---+---+---+
| v1| v2| v3|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|
|  1|  2|  2|
|  1|  2|  1|
|  1|  2|  0|
|  1|  1|  3|
|  1|  1|  2|
|  1|  1|  1|
|  1|  1|  0|
|  1|  0|  3|
|  1|  0|  2|
|  1|  0|  1|
|  1|  0|  0|
|  0|  2|  3|
|  0|  2|  2|
|  0|  2|  1|
|  0|  2|  0|
|  0|  1|  3|
|  0|  1|  2|
|  0|  1|  1|
|  0|  1|  0|
|  0|  0|  3|
|  0|  0|  2|
|  0|  0|  1|
|  0|  0|  0|
+---+---+---+
```

Your computation is pretty big: 
`(10953+1)*(10423+1)*(10053+1)=1148010922784`, about 1 trillion rows. I would suggest increase the numbers slowly, `spark` is not as fast as you think when it involves table joins.

Also, try use `broadcast` on all your initial DataFrames, i.e. `df1`, `df2`, `df3`. See if it helps.